# Page loading issue in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a code where I am trying to show some content using angularjs. We are pulling the data using PHP in the backend. But while doing so, I can view the contents when I inspect elements, but on the frontend the page is not loading up completely. If I refresh the page, the site gets loaded completely.

Here is my code snippet:

```
var mainapp=angular.module('mainApp',['ui.router','ngStorage','angularPayments']);
    mainapp.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider,$http){

    var views="./public/app/views";
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('index',{
            url : '/',
            views:{
                'header' : {
                    templateUrl : './public/app/views/header.html',
                    controller : "LoginController"
                },
                'content' : {
                    templateUrl : './public/app/views/home.html',
                    controller : "LoginController"
                },
                'footer' : {
                    templateUrl : './public/app/views/footer.html'
                }
            },


        })
        .state('postlogin',{
            url : '/app',
            views : {
                'header' : {
                    templateUrl : './public/app/views/header2.html',
                    controller : 'LoginController'
                },
                'content' : {
                    templateUrl : './public/app/views/post_login.html',
                    controller : 'PostLoginController'
                },
                'footer' : {
                    templateUrl : './public/app/views/footer.html'
                }
            },
            resolve : {
                gamedata : function($http,$q,$timeout){
                 var data = $q.defer();
                  // $timeout(function() {
                    $http({
                        method : "GET",
                        url : './server/open_games.php'
                    }).then(function successCallback(result){
                        console.log(result);
                        // $scope.games= result.data;
                        data.resolve(result.data);

                    },
                    function errorCallback(error){
                        data.resolve(error);
                    });

                        return data.promise; // this aborts the request!
                      // }, 1000);

                }
            }
        })
    }]);
```

Login Controller

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp');
    app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $http,$localStorage,$stateParams,$state,$location){


    $scope.login=function(){

        var data = {
            'email' : $scope.username,
            'password' : $scope.password
        };
        // alert(data.username);

        $http({
            method : "POST",
            url : "./server/login.php",
            data : data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        }).then(function successCallback(result, status, headers, config){

            location.href="#app";
            // $location.path('/app');

          // $state.go('postlogin',{},{ reload: true });
        },function errorCallback(data, status, headers, config,statusText){


        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: no errors in console